# Laplace equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I've been asked to compute the fundamental solution (in the distributional case) of the Laplacian. I have reach $u(r)=c\cdot r+c'$  for $r>0$ but i don't know how to prove that $\Delta  u=\delta_0$, any hint?

Comment: In dimension $1$, you have to check that $\int_{\Bbb R}(cr+c')\phi''(r)dr=\phi(0)$ for all $\phi$ smooth with compact support.

Comment: ok, I think at the end you get $c=\frac{1}{2}$ right?

Comment: I haven't done the computation. Maybe you can write it in an answer.